# Minecraft Forge setTextureName method not working

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

I am attempting to make an item using the latest version of Forge. For some reason, the setTextureName method gives me an error that says:

> The method setTextureName(String) is undefined for the type ItemKey

I have been trying to fix this for a while, and notice that when I remove the quotation marks from the colon the error for setTextureName disappears, but I get an error on the colon that says:

> Syntax error on token ":", delete this token

an error on the + sign that says

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String

and finally an error on "key" that says

> The method setTextureName(String) is undefined for the type ItemKey

This is my first time trying to make an item, so help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I just figured out that if I change `MODID` to `modid` in the setTextureName method I stop getting an error message for setTextureName but instead get an error for `modid` saying that

> modid cannot be resolved or is not a field

```
package com.arti.artismod;

import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;

public class ItemKey extends Item {
    private String name = "key";
    public ItemKey() {
        setUnlocalizedName(ArtisMod.MODID + "_" + "key");
        setTextureName(ArtisMod.MODID + ":" + "key");
        setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabMisc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Forge 1.8 uses a completely different method of managing textures. See [here](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php/topic,24263.0.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it would be greatly beneficial to learn Java before attempting to create a minecraft mod. There are many great tutorials out there (I personally started out learning with thenewboston's tutorials on youtube) and you'll gain a new useful skill!

Now onto your question. As newton1212 said, texture management has changed in 1.8. In fact, nearly everything related to rendering as a whole has been changed in the base game. JSON is now used for almost the entire system. This [tutorial](http://www.wuppy29.com/minecraft/1-8-tutorial/updating-1-7-to-1-8-part-2-basic-items/#sthash.dfGTFGlk.dpbs) covers updating a mod to 1.8 rather than creating one, however the updated files should be helpful to you anyways.

Good luck and feel free to ask any more questions you have.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It looks like just what I need. (Oh and by the way, I am pretty familiar with java, this is just the first time I'm making a mod with an item.)